# Trying to fetch inbox and outbox messages from Facebook in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

i need to get inbox and outbox messages in Facebook. but i get error as "operation couldn't be completed (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

```
NSString *uid=@"10000350024x";
NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/inbox",uid];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:path
                             parameters:NULL
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error is: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                          }
                      }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is due to facebook sdk. i had deleted it from the project and inserted new sdk. now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

What is `myuserid`? This should always be `me`, shouldn't it?

**Addition:** I assume you've asked for `read_mailbox` permissions

Comment: i used my hid which is provided by fb. in that it will be the uid number.

Comment: did you try with `@"/me/inbox"` for the graphPath?

Comment: yeah i did it.then also the same error. do i need to get any permissions in fblogin read permissions.

Comment: i getting the same error. already i got all access from access tokens in fb. i am asking about any read permissions like @"    FBLoginView *loginView =
    [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_likes",@"read_mailbox"]];"